# Copying strings to an array

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy

In my code's output I find that the strings I am printing are all `(null)` even though I input `count` strings of characters < 31.

```
char name[31];
char *names[32];
int count = 5;
for (int i =0; i<count;i++) {
        scanf("%s",name);
        names[i]=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
        strcpy(names[i],name);
    }

for (int i =0; i<count;i++) {
    printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[count]);
}
```

Comment: Probably a typo, but `printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[count]);` should be `printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[i]);` - otherwise, you're printing an unallocated string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use `names[i]` in stead of `names[count]`

```c
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", i+1, names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you're indexing names with count but your code initialize string only up to count - 1.
Changing printf this way:

```
printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[i]);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the `printf` function, you need to modify it in this way:

`printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[count]);`  => `printf("%d: %s\n",i+1,names[i]);`